# Free C++ code samples

Tags: c++

I would like to download some code samples (or even full projects) to learn from. The only place I know of is Sourceforge, but I want top-notch, flawless* code. Not to say there is anything wrong with SF but it's a toss up, and I don't want to learn from someones bad habits.
I've been through gametutorials.com and nehe.gamedev.net, but I would prefer to find something that's been done recently with best practices in mind.

*Obviously nothing is going to be perfect

Answer (score 7):

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/).

Comment: This must be the shortest answer I've upvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the source of web browsers like Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend Firefox code base to anyone, it is laden with legacy code. Chrome is not too bad though from what i've seen.

Answer (score 0):

Use an open source search engine like [Koders](http://www.koders.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[Qt is written pretty well.](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/trees/4.7/src)

Answer (score 0):

Everyone's got different ideas of what's top-notch, as there are fundamental design trade-offs with no correct answer (e.g. performance, memory usage, maintainability, reusability/generality, simplicity, clarity, concision, portability...), and one programmer's idea of elegance is another's pompous over-engineering, and yet another's over-simplistic amateurism... :-/.

Boost code is good, but complicated by a different balance of concerns than most application code: generally portability, performance & memory usage, generality, elegance of usage, and minimising misusage are prioritised massively above simplicity, clarity or concision of implementation.

I think you're better off picking some code that does something you're interested in, then in your passion to change it you'll learn see the implications of the design compromises, good and bad.  A smaller project where you can rearchitect the solution and experiment with alternatives is great.  No substitute for experience.